# Interacting with files and directories on VSTO Word addin in Ribbon.cs

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, interop, office-addins

Please help. The thing what I need is quite simple. I need a menu from files and folders. If I press the folder(name), then the menu expands and I get list from that folder and so on. I tried to use DropDown and I can get there the file names or/and folder names. But if I will press on item, the drop down list will fold. (Its not what I need)

```
//dropDown lable is: combo
 DirectoryInfo obj = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\install\");//
            DirectoryInfo[] folders = obj.GetDirectories();
            var filtered = folders.Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden));
            string str = "";
            RibbonDropDownItem ddItem0 = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();

            ddItem0.Label = $"{str}";
            combo.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo file in filtered)
            {
                str = file.Name;

                RibbonDropDownItem ddItem1 = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                ddItem1.Label = $"Kaust:{str}";
                combo.Items.Add(ddItem1);
```

Maby I need to use Menu instead of DropDown? But how can I do that? 
Shortly: I have a folder. There is files and folders inside. I need a Ribbon "button" to chose files and open folders inside this "button".

Answer (score 1):

Ribbon UI is a static thing from its birth. The only possible dynamic changes can be implemented by using ribbon callbacks. Unfortunately, the Ribbon designer available in VSTO add-ins doesn't provide all features of the Fluent UI, so you must switch to using a raw XML markup specifying callbacks you are interested in. See [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019) for getting started quickly. Note, you can export your existing custom UI to a ribbon XML file.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#dropdown)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

To refresh your custom UI you need to use the [IRibbonUI.Invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate?view=office-pia) and [IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol) methods that allow invalidating the cached values for all of the controls (or just a specified one) of the Ribbon user interface. So, when an item is chosen in one control you may force other controls to update its state and content.

Basically, calling the `Invalidate` or `InvalidateControl` method you may force your ribbon callbacks to be invoked anew. For example, if an add-in writer implements the `getImage` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place for the control until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `InvalidateControl` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached.

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI
Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set MyRibbon = Ribbon
End Sub
Sub myFunction()
‘ Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in’s controls
MyRibbon.Invalidate()

End Sub
```

Also, you may find the `dynamicMenu` control helpful because it provides the `getContent` callback which gets an XML string that contains the contents of this dynamic menu.